# Xamarin.Forms - Sharing and Synchronizing an SQLite Database

Tags: android, sqlite, xamarin.forms

My Xamarin.Forms app for Android phone uses a SQLite database, stored locally. I would like a user to be able to synchronize his database with a copy placed on a server in the cloud, and to give access to this file to another user to have the same data on 2 different phones. I found LITESYNC that allows you to synchronize a local SQLite database with a SQLite database located in the cloud, but I do not understand their explanations.
What is the procedure to follow to implement LITESYNC (or another software)?

Thanks in advance to whoever can help me.

Comment: if you have a question about using a particular library or tool, including a link to it would be really helpful.  "I do not understand their explanations" - again, what specifically don't you understand?  Linking to the docs or quoting the section you're confused by would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

The local SQLite database can not support two different devices to visit the same database file, you can check this [Can multiple applications or multiple instances of the same application access a single database file at the same time?](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5)

There are some options you can refer to:

- First, you can use the firebase [Get started with Cloud Storage on
  Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/start).
- Second, you can use the SQL Server.